# Delay in the beginning of solution for two ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

I have two couple ODEs and the second one has a delay in the time for starting. I mean, the first ODE starts at t=0 and the second one at  t=20. How can I solve the second one in the correct time after the first one has already started to be solved?

the system is:

```
NDSolve[{ 
  mRNA'[t] == im (1 - Exp[-Kb Yab] - Kdm mRNA[t], 
  P'[t] == Kt mRNA[t] - Kdp P[t], mRNA[0] == 0, 
  P[0] == 0}, {mRNA[t], P[t]}, {t, 0, 400}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
im = Kb = Yab = Kdm = Kt = Kdp = 1;
NDSolve[{mRNA'[t] == im (1 - Exp[-Kb Yab] - Kdm mRNA[t]), 
  P'[t] == If[t > 20, Kt mRNA[t] - Kdp P[t], 0], mRNA[0] == 0, 
  P[0] == 0}, {mRNA, P}, {t, 0, 400}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the first equation is totally independent of the second variable P, you can solve it analytically first. Saying "the second starts at t = 20", I think you mean P[20]==0 and for lower t.

```
im = Kb = Yab = Kdm = Kt = Kdp = 1;

mRNAsol = mRNA /. First@
   DSolve[{Derivative[1][mRNA][t] == 1 - 1/E - mRNA[t], mRNA[0] == 0},
 mRNA, t]

(*   Function[{t}, (-1 + E) E^(-1 - t) (-1 + E^t)]   *)

Psol[t_] = Piecewise[{{P[t] /. 
 First@DSolve[{Derivative[1][P][t] == mRNAsol[t] - P[t], 
    P[20] == 0}, P, t], t > 20}}, 0]

(*   Piecewise[{{E^(-1 - t)*(-20 + 20*E + 
        E^20 - E^21 - E^t + 
        E^(1 + t) + t - E*t), 
   t > 20}}, 0]   *)

Plot[{mRNAsol[t], Psol[t]}, {t, 0, 40}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
   PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]